# Using SSL when browsing to an IP address

Tags: ssl, iis

The server is behind a firewall and has a private IP and I need to get to the public IP of the domain that it is hosting...

I have several sites with several Host Name bindings and they all work fine over SSL (i.e. https://example.com), but I need to get to it just using the IP address (i.e. https://123.45.67.89) and I can't figure out how to do the bindings because it doesn't allow an IP address as the host name.  Browsing to just the IP gives me a 'Connection Not Private' message.

Answer (score 1):

a security certificate must be granted to a host name e.g. example.com

You cannot issue a certificate to an ip address.

When you browse via ip and the certificate is served up, it does not match the address you have entered and is correctly telling you that the certificate is not valid for the site you are wishing to view

Comment: Certificates containing IP addresses can be created. But support is mixed in the browsers (IE needs it wrongly in CN, others correctly as IP SAN entry). And while public CA's should no longer issue certificates for IP addresses one can do it with own CA's.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate provided by the server is probably not issued for the IP address and that's why it does not match the URL (with IP as target) you entered. You have to access the server with a name which matches the certificate which means that you need some DNS settings which map the name contained in the certificate to the external visible IP address and then you can access the server by its correct name. For testing you can do such mapping inside your local hosts file. But if the server should be visible from outside for others too you need to configure the public DNS for the domains served by the firewalled server so that the mapping to the public IP address is publicly visible.